# Trying to learn JavaScript and nothing is working on my page

Tags: javascript

The Goal:

A button which displays an alert with "Hello world!" and some radio buttons which display a warning when the third one is selected.

The HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>hello world</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <meta name="description" content="">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <p>text</p>
        <a href="#">link</a>
        <button>button</button>
        <form>
            <fieldset>
                <legend>Legend</legend>
                    <label for="radio1">Option 1</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="option-1" id="radio1"/>
                    <label for="radio2">Option 2</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="option-2" id="radio2"/>
                    <label for="radio3">Option 3</label>
                        <input type="radio" name="radio-buttons" value="option-3" id="radio3"/>
                        <p id="warn">No, pick another one.</p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The CSS:

Most of this really doesn't matter. The important thing is #warn which is supposed to only show when the third option is selected.

```
a,
button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}

fieldset {
    width: 245px;
    height: 75px;
    background: #dfe;
    position: relative;
}

legend {
    background: white;
}

#warn {
    display: none;
    background: #d33;
    color: #fff;
    font-family: helvetica;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px;
    margin: 0 -12px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 52px;
    width: 239px;
}
```

The JavaScript:

I think the problem is in my event handlers, but I don't know for sure. BTW yes I know there's some extraneous stuff here; like I said I'm just screwing around.

```
// variables
var p        = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
var a        = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
var button   = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var fieldset = document.getElementsByTagName("fieldset");

var radio1   = document.getElementById("radio1");
var radio2   = document.getElementById("radio2");
var radio3   = document.getElementById("radio3");

var warn     = document.getElementById("warn");

// functions
function prepareEventHandlers() {

    button.onclick = function() {
        alert("Hello world!")
    };

    radio3.onfocus = function() {
        warn.setAttribute("display","inherit")
    }
}

// window onload
window.onload = function() {
    prepareEventHandlers();
}
```

Comment: is this code put in `script.js` ? If yes, then have you given the correct path to that script?

Comment: I suggest you strip everything out of your page except the button and then work on the javascript until that works. After that, go for more.

Comment: You can probably remove all the CSS from your question as it doesn't seem pertinent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Notice the name of the function:

```
document.getElementsByTagName()
                // ^ That's an "s", so the function
                //   returns an array of elements.
```

`button.onclick` won't work because `button` is an array of buttons (I would name it `buttons`), so you have to iterate:

```
for (var i = 0; i < button.length; i++) {
  button[i].onclick = ...
}
```

Since you have only one button, I would just give it an `id` and use `document.getElementById()` to fetch the single button and attach the `onclick` handler.

Comment: Alternatively, `var button   = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];` to get the first (and in this case only) button. Note the `[0]`. But it would probably be better to give the button an ID and use `getElementById` instead.

Comment: It works! thanks, I get it now. So what about the radio button warning?

Comment: `setAttribute()` is for HTML attributes. Since you're changing a CSS attribute, use `element.style.display = 'block';`.

Answer (score 3):

First, go fo button like this,

```
var button   = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
```

`getElementsByTagName` returns the array of matched elements...

For radio button
Try this

`display` is a `CSS` property. Using `display` as an `HTML attribute` will not hide or show content. You have to access `CSS` properties using `style` attribute. like,

```
radio3.onclick = function() {
        warn.style.display = "inherit";
    }
```

Comment: The path was indeed correct. Adding [0] fixed the button problem, What about the radio button warning?